# += operator within .css method in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is there any way to achieve a += operator within the css operator (assuming ui.value in the example has a numerical value)

Something like this(which doesn't work):

```
$("#resume_holder").contents().find('body').children().css('font-size', +=ui.value);
```

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte Not like that either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#resume_holder")
    .contents()
    .find('body')
    .children()
    .css('font-size', '+=' + ui.value);
```

(if you're using jQuery >= 1.6)

according to the docs for css:

> As of jQuery 1.6, .css() accepts relative values similar to
>   .animate(). Relative values are a string starting with += or -= to
>   increment or decrement the current value. For example, if an element's
>   padding-left was 10px, .css( "padding-left", "+=15" ) would result in
>   a total padding-left of 25px.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/JMRPf/ (trivial I know, but proof that it works)

Comment: Neat. I always thought you has to put in a unit when changing css values such as font size. But apparently it assumes the unit type already set. Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: Yea that did it -- pretty cool. I should have tried that I just assumed that it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You could keep the actual value of font-size into a variable, add the ui.value, and asign it back:

```
var crtFontSize = parseInt($("#resume_holder").contents().find('body').children().css('font-size'));
crtFontSize += ui.value;
$("#resume_holder").contents().find('body').children().css('font-size', crtFontSize + 'px');
```

Comment: Thanks -- While .css() accepts +=, it does not accept *= -- so this was great.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `animate` method of jquery, but that would display the result gradually.. is that a problem?

```
$("#resume_holder").contents().find('body').children().animate('font-size', ui.value);
```

That would change the current font size, to what `ui.value` contains.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no.

However this can be accomplished as follows (untested):

```
$("#resume_holder").contents().find('body').children().each(function() {
    $(this).css('font-size', $(this).css('font-size') + ui.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about `css` but you can try to implement it using `animate` method.

```
$("#resume_holder").contents().find('body').children()
.animate({ fontSize: '+='+ui.value });
```